# After URL Rewrite to subfolder, is there away to keep relative image paths?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

We've setup a URL Rewrite Rule so that:

www.MySite.com/bhgre/

rewrites to

www.MySite.com/landingpages/bhgre.aspx

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="BHGRE" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="bhgre/?$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/landingpages/bhgre.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

The rewrite works fine and the URL stays with /bhgre.  However, the actual webpage makes use of relative paths to images in it's own subfolder (i.e. images/image1.png).  The page is getting a 404 because the images is being pulled from

www.mysite.com/images/image1.png

instead of

www.mysite.com/landingpages/images/image1.png

Is there some other technique within URLRewrite to make this work?  Or, is the only solution to use full paths to the images sub folder?

Thanks!